# Stream is closing when using Async/Await

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I have a little service to upload blobs to Azure Storage. I am trying to use it from a WebApi async action, but my `AzureFileStorageService` says the stream is closed.

I am new to async/await, are there any good resources to help me better understand it?

**WebApi Controller**

```
public class ImageController : ApiController
{
    private IFileStorageService fileStorageService;

    public ImageController(IFileStorageService fileStorageService)
    {
        this.fileStorageService = fileStorageService;
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType));
        }

        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider()).ContinueWith((task) =>
        {

            foreach (var item in task.Result.Contents)
            {
                using (var fileStream = item.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
                {
                    fileStorageService.Save(@"large/Sam.jpg", fileStream);
                }

                item.Dispose();
            }

        });

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**AzureFileStorageService**

```
public class AzureFileStorageService : IFileStorageService
{
    public async void Save(string path, Stream source)
    {
        await CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"])
            .CreateCloudBlobClient()
            .GetContainerReference("images")
            .GetBlockBlobReference(path)
            .UploadFromStreamAsync(source); // source throws a stream is disposed exception
    }
}
```

Comment: `item.Dispose();` is redundant; `Dispose()` is already called on `item` when it leaves the scope of the `using` block.

Comment: In fact, that may actually be the problem.  Everything is set up with `async` and `await`; the `using` block may be closing the stream prematurely, before your result is retrieved.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - So `item.Dispose()` is called as well as `Dispose()` on the `Result` which in this case is a `Stream`?

Comment: You have a problem with your `Save()` method: you're not returning a `Task`, and so the calling method has no way to wait for it to finish. And so immediately after you call it you leave the `using` block and the stream is disposed, likely way before the save is complete

Comment: @Sam: Yeah, you're right; it's two different disposes.  But the problem remains; you're closing/disposing the stream prematurely.

Comment: @dlev - Can you return just an empty `Task`? Or do I have to have it return a `Task<some type>`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - So just to be clear, `using` will only dispose one item correct? So in this case, the `Result` is disposed of and not the `item`?

Comment: `item.Dispose()` is fine: the `using` statement is disposing of the stream, not the item.

Comment: @Sam See my answer; `Task` is fine if your `async` method doesn't return a value but you will want to `await` it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a problem with your Save() method: you're not returning a Task, and so the calling method has no way to wait for it to finish. That would be fine if you just wanted to fire and forget it, but you can't do that because the stream you pass in is going to be disposed as soon as the `Save()` method returns (thanks to the `using` statement).

Instead, you're going to have to either return a `Task` and `await` in the calling method, or you're going to have to not have the file stream in a `using` block, and instead let the `Save()` method dispose of it when its finished.

One way you could re-write your code would be as follows:

(snippet of calling method):

```
    var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider());
    foreach (var item in result.Contents)
    {
        using (var fileStream = await item.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            await fileStorageService.Save(@"large/Sam.jpg", fileStream);
        }

        item.Dispose();
    }
```

And the Save method:

```
public async Task Save(string path, Stream source)
{
    await CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"])
        .CreateCloudBlobClient()
        .GetContainerReference("images")
        .GetBlockBlobReference(path)
        .UploadFromStreamAsync(source);
}
```

Comment: Also, `ContinueWith` can be replaced with `await`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Do you have any good recommendations of sites that explain the await/async in a simple clear way?

Comment: @StephenCleary - `await` where can be replaced?

Comment: @Sam The MSDN docs are a decent place to start, and both Stephen Toub's and Eric Lippert's respective sets of blog posts are also good, accessible resources. And, to be frank, Stephen Cleary has a nice series as well :)

Comment: @Sam Your code currently uses `ContinueWith` on a `Task` before awaiting that result. But `await` is essentially a way to bypass the need for `ContinueWith` altogether: just `await` the original task, and then the rest of the method automatically becomes the continuation. So really you can just remove the `ContinueWith`.

Comment: @dlev - Would you mind refactoring the code I provided in your answer so I can see exactly what you are saying... I am new, so please bear with me :)

Comment: @Sam I've updated the answer to illustrate one approach.

Comment: @Sam I updated the answer because it was using a .Result. This is a strongly discouraged pattern (mixing async and then waiting using .Result / .Wait(). It might lead to deadlocks in ASP.NET but in general when you start async/await you should stay async/await throughout the code. .Result and .Wait() are big red flags to watch for.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this AzureBlobUpload sample we just released a few weeks ago:

The previous answer is definitely a good fix. This is just a complete end to end official sample (perhaps for other folks to get started on).

https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/AzureBlobsFileUploadSample/ReadMe.txt